# jQuery How to multiply the value and get the total

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to multiply the value and get the total. i tried code below i attached .
when i add the two numbers it is working fine. but when i multiply two value getting problem.
This how i add the values

```
 sum += Number($(this).val());
```

instead of + i put as * this symbols

```
sum *= Number($(this).val());
```

Result is not displaying with no errors . i attached code below please see the code and give me the good answer thanks.

**This the Form**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control price" id="price" name="price" placeholder="price" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Qty</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control price" id="qty" name="qty" placeholder="qty" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total Cost</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total_cost" name="total_cost" placeholder="Total Cost" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is jQuery**

```
function total()
{
    // we used jQuery 'keyup' to trigger the computation as the user type
    $('.price').keyup(function () {

        // initialize the sum (total price) to zero
        var sum = 0;

        // we use jQuery each() to loop through all the textbox with 'price' class
        // and compute the sum for each loop
        $('.price').each(function() {
            sum += Number($(this).val());

        });

        // set the computed value to 'totalPrice' textbox
        $('#total_cost').val(sum);

    });

}
```

Comment: Well, if you multiply 0 by anything, you get 0. Set `sum` to 1 instead if you want to find the product of all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `sum =1` because `sum = 0` will give always 0 on multiplication

So do:-

```
var sum = 1;

sum = sum * Number($(this).val());
```

Or

```
var sum = 1;

sum *= Number($(this).val());
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.price').keyup(function(){
    var sum = 1;
    $('.price').each(function() {
      if($(this).val()){
        sum *= Number($(this).val());
      }
    });
    $('#total_cost').val(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control price" id="price" name="price" placeholder="price" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Qty</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control price" id="qty" name="qty" placeholder="qty" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total Cost</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total_cost" name="total_cost" placeholder="Total Cost" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for you good answer sir. now working. qty how to set as 1 on the textboxfield